# Display information related to the currently selected record on a list page

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

You need to display information related to the currently selected record on a Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 list page. What should I use?

1. A. Action Pane
2. B. Cues Fact Box
3. C. Fast Tab
4. D. Preview Pane

Correct Answer: B
My Response: C (Incorrect)
I don't anderstand why is it a cue fact box ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fast tab" is not correct because you do not use fast tabs in [list pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg853328.aspx).

I would consider both B and D correct.

Cues fact box because it updates the information when you select another record in the list page.

So does a preview pane, but usually it is information from the *same* record rather than *related* records, fx. Customer list page. In the Sales order list page you see order line information in the preview pane, I consider this *related* information, but it should probably be restricted to child records only.